# Parallelismus mit Genitiv

Tags: grammar, genitive, parallelism

Aus [Spiegel online](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/auch-michel-platini-angeschlagen-kommentar-zu-ermittlungen-gegen-sepp-blatter-a-1054862.html):

> Das ist ein Satz, der die Statik nicht nur der Fifa gefährdet, sondern die des Europäischen Fußballverbandes Uefa gleich mit.

Ich empfinde diesen Satz als ungrammatisch, denn „nicht nur“ kommt hinter dem Substantiv „die Statik“, „sondern“ aber davor. Richtig sollte es meiner Meinung nach entweder

> (a) …, der **nicht nur** die Statik der Fifa gefährdet, **sondern** die des 
>   Europäischen Fußballverbandes Uefa gleich mit.

oder

> (b) …, der die Statik **nicht nur** der Fifa gefährdet, **sondern** des Europäischen Fußballverbandes Uefa gleich mit.

heißen. Habe ich hier Recht?

Comment: Ja, Du hast Recht. Die Satzstellung ist schlecht.

Comment: Mich stört mehr die Großschreibung von _Europäischer Fußballverband_. Ist zwar möglich, wenn man es als festen Begriff auffaßt (und es gibt ja nur einen europäischen Fußballverband), aber es scheint mir kein solcher zu sein.

Comment: Nein, du hast nicht Recht (jedenfalls nicht nach meinem Sprachempfinden). Die Satzstellung des zitierten Satzes ist völlig in Ordnung. Ich empfinde auch (a) als gut (gleich gut wie der Originalsatz). Variante (b) ist für mich die schlechteste, denn hier vermisse ich das Demonstrativpronomen zwischen »sondern« und »des«.

Comment: Meines Erachtens hat der Satz ein weiteres Problem, nämlich die Konstruktion *nicht nur A, sondern B gleich mit* statt entweder *nicht nur A, sondern auch B* und *A und B gleich mit. – sondern* und *gleich mit* passen nicht wirklich zusammen. Ersteres baut einen Gegensatz auf, zweiteres ist eher ergänzend.

Comment: What @Wrzlprmft said. Und wenn ich mich für einen der oberen Sätze entscheiden müsste, so wählte ich den mit (a) gekennzeichneten. Ich bin norddeutscher Eingeborener.

Comment: Bei "Das ist ein Satz, der nicht nur die Statik der Fifa gefährdet ..." würde ich als Fortsetzung "..., sondern auch die Fassade" erwarten. Hier soll betont werden, dass es bei der Bedrohung um 2 Organisationen geht, beide Male um die Statik. Das erzwingt zwar nicht das Aufschieben des "nicht nur", aber entschuldigt es m.E. ganz gut. Der Europäische Fußballverband ist die UEFA, letzteres würde ich entweder per Komma abtrennen oder alternativ nutzen, jedenfalls großschreiben. Disclaimer: Man würde nicht mich fragen, um Kommas sicher zu setzen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Du hast guten Grund zu zweifeln, aber du hast nicht Recht.

Wir haben es hier mit einer Variante der mehrteiligen Konjunktion *nicht nur … sondern auch* zu tun, wobei *gleich mit* die Rolle (wenn auch nicht die Position) von *auch* übernehmen soll. Dazu später, ich tue erst mal so, als wäre der Satz mit *auch* formuliert worden.

Die detaillierteste Quelle, die ich zu mehrteiligen Konjunktionen finden konnte, ist (mal wieder) [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/mehrteilig.html). Dort steht

> Mehrteilige Konjunktionen sind Konjunktionen die aus zwei Teilen bestehen. **Der erste Teil steht vor dem ersten zu verbindenden Element**, der zweite Teil steht zwischen den zu verbindenden Elementen.

*Nicht nur* steht vor *der FIFA*, die FIFA wäre also das erste Element, dem in der Gegenüberstellung die UEFA als zu verbindendes Element entspricht, die deshalb allein im zweiten Teil auftauchen dürfte, so wie in Deinem Beispiel b). Hingegen verweist *die* im zweiten Teil auf *die Statik*, die aber nach der Logik gar nicht zu den verbindenden Elementen gehört und deshalb dort nicht hingehört.

Aber: auch in b) ist die Aussage eine Gegenüberstellung von *die Statik der FIFA* und *die Statik der UEFA*, auch wenn *die Statik* im zweiten Teil nicht mehr auftaucht. Die Frage ist deshalb eher, warum *nicht nur* im ersten Teil trotz der zitierten Aussage hinter *die Statik* rutschen kann. Die Antwort liefern die Freiheiten des deutschen Satzbaus und eine Aussage weiter unten auf der gleichen canoo-Seite:

> Der Teil *nicht nur* wird meist wie ein Adverb in den ersten Satz eingegliedert.

Dazu ein Beispiel (wir bleiben beim Fußball):

> a) Die Tore von Müller, Meier und Schmidt waren entscheidend für den Erfolg.
>   b) Insbesondere die Tore von Müller, aber auch von Meier und Schmidt waren entscheidend für den Erfolg.
>   c) Die Tore insbesondere von Müller, aber auch von Meier und Schmidt waren entscheidend für den Erfolg.

b) und c) heben gegenüber a) die Bedeutung der Tore von Müller hervor. Während b) aber auch so weitergehen könnte:

> b') Insbesondere die Tore von Müller, aber auch die Paraden von Meier und die Pässe von Schmidt waren entscheidend für den Erfolg.

ist in c) sehr früh im Satz klar, dass es nur um Tore verschiedener Spieler geht. Der Preis dafür ist ein etwas sperriger wirkender Satzbau. Gerechtfertigt ist er vor allem im schriftlichen Gebrauch. Mündlich könnte man den gleichen Effekt erzielen, in dem man in b) *Müller* betont.

Nach dem gleichen Prinzip hat sich der Autor des Originalsatzes entschieden, *nicht nur* zwischen Statik und FIFA zu schieben, und nach der oben zitierten „Regel“ (ich weiß nicht, ob man es so nennen soll – „Erklärung“ wäre vielleicht besser) „darf“ er das auch, denn es ist eine Position, an der prinzipiell auch ein Adverb wie *insbesondere* stehen könnte. Er erreicht dadurch eine stärkere Betonung der FIFA und signalisiert dem Leser etwas früher, dass der Statik der FIFA die Statik von etwas anderem gegenübergestellt werden soll.

Ob nun mit dem Demonstrativpronomen *die* im zweiten Teil nochmal explizit *die Statik* referenziert wird oder nicht, ist eine Stilfrage. Grammatikalisch ist das genauso egal wie

> die Tore von Müller, Meier und Schmidt
>   die Tore von Müller, die von Meier und die von Schmidt
>   die Tore von Müller, die Tore von Meier und die Tore von Schmidt

Nicht egal ist es hingegen, wenn es um die Verwendung von *gleich mit* geht. Das müsste eigentlich so verwendet werden:

> Der Satz gefährdet die Statik der FIFA, und er gefährdet die Statik der UEFA gleich mit.

was sich verkürzen lässt zu

> Der Satz gefährdet die Statik der FIFA, und die der UEFA gleich mit. (*)

aber ich habe große Zweifel, ob man das *die* auch weglassen dürfte. Auf jeden Fall wäre es dann sehr schwer verständlich. Der Autor hat jedenfalls diese Wendung, die semantisch ja auch ein „auch“ in sich trägt, auf die Konjunktion *nicht nur … sondern auch* übertragen und braucht deshalb das Demonstrativpronomen *die* im zweiten Teil. Wie Du aus den anderen Reaktionen hier siehst, wird das von vielen verstanden und als ok empfunden. Für manche klingt es aber auch befremdlich bis falsch. Ich vermute, das liegt daran, dass *nicht nur … sondern auch* eine Doppelnatur von Verbindung und Gegensatz hat:

> Er hat nicht „Ja“ gesagt, sondern „Nein“.
>   Er hat nicht nur „Ja“ gesagt, sondern auch „Nein“.
>   Er hat „Ja“ gesagt und „Nein“.

Wer da eher den Gegensatz heraushört, wird *gleich mit* in dem Zusammenhang als unpassend empfinden. Wer hingegen eher das Verbindende heraushört, für den passt es.

---

(*) Was das Komma angeht: ich glaube, es lässt sich als Nachtrag rechtfertigen. Im Zweifel einen Gedankenstrich setzen, aus Lesbarkeitsgründen würde ich dort jedenfalls vor *und* ein Trennzeichen empfehlen.

Answer (score 7):

Für mich ist der Satz völlig akzeptabel, wie auch die Umformulierung (a).* Hingegen klingt die Umformulierung (b) etwas seltsam; das hängt allerdings vor allem am *gleich mit* (und ist für die Frage somit nicht entscheidend), denn „nicht nur der Fifa, sondern auch des europäischen Fußballverbands Uefa“ wäre für mich wiederum in Ordnung.

Auch die *Duden*-Grammatik (4. Auflage) scheint in der Wiederholung von mehr umgebender Konstruktion als unbedingt nötig kein Problem zu sehen, denn sie führt in Randziffer 656 unter anderem folgendes Beispiel an:

> Er ist nicht nur dumm, sondern er ist auch faul.

---

*Genaugenommen ist Umformulierung (a) allerdings nicht zum ursprünglichen Satz äquivalent, denn im Original wird ein Gegensatz zwischen Fifa und Uefa hergestellt, in der umformulierten Fassung aber zwischen ihrer jeweiligen Statik. Ein Unterschied in der Bedeutung ist hier aber nicht zu erkennen.

Comment: Ich stimme in allem mit dir überein, nur nicht in der Frage der Bedeutungen. Denn auch der Originalsatz vergleicht nicht direkt Fifa und Uefa, sondern ebenfalls deren Statiken, so wie auch Satz (a). Auch im Originalsatz sind die Statiken der beiden Organisationen gefährdet, nicht die Organisationen selbst.

Comment: Weder wird ein Gegensatz in der Statik behauptet, noch deren Statik miteinander verglichen. Es wird lediglich unterstellt, dass deren Statik unabhängig voneinander gefährdet werden kann. "Das ist ein Eisberg, der die Route nicht nur der Victoria gefährdet, sondern die der Virginie gleich mit." Ob die die gleiche Route haben oder nicht spielt keine Rolle, sie haben jeweils eine Route, unabhängig voneinander.